# apt - checking if a similar package has been installed

Tags: apt, dpkg

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298066/check-if-a-package-is-installed-and-then-install-it-if-its-not) explains how to find out if a given Debian package has been installed, but it does not take into account "synonyms" when installing via `apt-get`.

For instance, if I try `apt-get install libncurses-dev`, apt-get replies:

```
Note, selecting 'libncurses5-dev' instead of 'libncurses-dev'
```

And then it installs that package (`libncurses5-dev`), which is fine by me.

But what if I want to make a script to detect if the package has already been installed?

`dpkg -s libncurses-dev` replies that the package is not installed, which is indeed correct, since it's `libncurses5-dev` that was installed. But I'd like my script to detect that, in this case, it no longer needs to install `libncurses-dev`.

I could not find an option in `apt-get` to check if the given package *or one of its providers* has already been installed, such that my script would work when checking for `libncurses-dev` as well as for `libncurses5-dev`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write a script to check to see if package `libncurses-dev` or its alias has been installed, consider the following program flow:

1. Check if the package has been installed with `dpkg` using the exact name, `libncurses-dev` in this case.
2. If the above does not evaluate to true, then search `apt` for the package you are looking for using the non-aliased name:

   ```
   $ apt-cache search libncurses-dev
   libncurses5-dev - developer's libraries for ncurses
   ```

It appears that `apt-cache search` will return the 'alias' if the package has one.

3. If #1 evaluates false and #2 returns an alias, just grab the package's alias and try #1 again.

Check `dpkg` again with the alias name of the package, in this case it would be `libncurses5-dev`. If `dpkg` does not find the package by an alias (actually a superseded package) then it must not be installed.

Comment: Thanks, but on my machine I had to use `apt-cache search`, since `apt-get search` resulted in `E: Invalid operation search`. Is it a typo, or does your `apt-get` include the `search` operation?

Comment: @anol Ah yes, it was indeed a typo, thanks for catching that.

Comment: There's just a minor issue I had: even after removing the package (including via `purge`), `apt-cache` still lists it. And unlike `dpkg`, it doesn't include a status letter (such as `i` for installed), so I guess it would be necessary to use `apt-cache search` for the synonym, then `dpkg` to check if it's installed... a bit more complex than I expected, but still doable. Could you please confirm if all of that is required, or if you see a simpler way?

Comment: Perhaps i was unclear, use `dpkg` to see if the package is installed on your system, this is always at step 1. Use `apt-cache search` only to generate the alias to use when rechecking via `dpkg`. `apt-cache` will not reflect installed packages, so it is unaffected if you purge a package, I would only use this to find aliases to check in `dpkg`.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a job for an [aptitude search](http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s04.html).

```
$ aptitude -F %p search '~Plibncurses-dev'
libncurses5-dev                                                                 
libncurses5-dev:i386
$ aptitude -F %p search '~Plibncurses-dev ~rnative'
libncurses5-dev                                                                 
$ aptitude -F %p search '~Plibncurses-dev ~rnative ~i'
libncurses5-dev
```

That last one would print nothing if `libncurses5-dev` wasn't installed.

Comment: Can I expect aptitude to be as widely available as apt-cache on a given machine? I mean, would there be potential users who might have one installed but not the other?

Comment: @anol No, aptitude isn't as common. `apt-cache` is part of the base installation (it's in the `apt` package), `aptitude` is a separate package that isn't always installed.